# GCP Datastore Python - InvalidArgument: 400 A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations affecting the same entity

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Cloud Run application that writes to records to Cloud Datastore periodically. Each record has the same key every time, so I am updating the record when writing.
The problem is that this application gets a lot of requests and hence autoscales. When all these autoscaled instances write to the Cloud Datastore, sometimes they all attempt it at the same time and that is when I see exception mentioned below:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations affecting the same entity.
```

Below is a skeleton code of the upload function.

```
def datastore_upload(records: list):
    client = datastore.Client()
    kind = "some_kind"
    entities = []
    for record in records:
        name = record['name']
        key = client.key(kind, name)
        task = datastore.Entity(key=key)
        task['x'] = record['x']
        task['y'] = record['y']
        entities.append(task)
    client.put_multi(entities)
```

Comment: May be worth looking into PubSub topic to hook the message request queue

Answer (score 0):

You can easily work around this issue by tracking which entities are being updated, e.g.

```
def datastore_upload(records: list):
    client = datastore.Client()
    kind = "some_kind"
    entities = {}
    for record in records:
        name = record['name']
        key = client.key(kind, name)
        task = datastore.Entity(key=key)
        task['x'] = record['x']
        task['y'] = record['y']
        # Keep the last update for each task.
        entities[name] = task
    client.put_multi(list(entities.values()))
```

Comment: This may work in other cases but won't in mine as this function is being called by many workers of autoscaled instances simultaneously.

Comment: Why won't it work.  The error is that you are putting the same entity twice into the same batch write call.  De-duplicating within the write fixes the issue with the RPC.  If your error was related to conflicts between RPCs, then that would require a different solution (e.g. transactions).

Comment: My issue is the later one. How would one solve this using transactions?